# How to filter the rows of a gridview in yii using radio buttons

Tags: php, javascript, yii

I used the below code to create two radio buttons(approved messages and rejected messages) in Yii framework

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeRadioButtonList($model, 'Approved', array('Approved Messages', 'Rejected Messages'), array('labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'),'separator'=>'')) ?>
```

Now I have to filter and display all the rows in CGridView of the table where column 'approved' has value=1 when I click on "approved messages" radio button and all the rows in CGridView of the table where column 'Approved' has value=0 when I click on "rejected messages" radio button. How can I do this

[image: Radio Button]

Answer (score 0):

I used a drop down for this, the values are Yes and No.  Just translate the `approved` column into text using the following code:

```
array(
  'name' => 'approved',
  'value' => '($data->approved ? "Yes" : "No")',
  'filter' = >CHtml::dropDownList('Approved', '',  
            array(
                ' '=>'All',
                '1'=>'On',
                '0'=>'Off',
            )
        ),
)
```

This link is where I got this info: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/30694-cgridview-filter-dropdown-from-array/

I googled using `cgridview filter example`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, lets put in the radio buttons instead of all the dropdowns haha. 
I assume you have your view set up something like this:

```
// view/index.php  (or similar)
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>Message::model(),
    'columns'=>
    [
        'id',
        'username',
        'email:email',
        'approved'=>[
            'name'=>'approved',
            'filter'=>$this->approvedFilter(), 
            // I like moving stuff like this out of the way.
            // But maybe it's smarter to put it in your model instead?
        ]
    ]
));
```

Next for the controller.

```
// MessageController.php  (or similar)
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = Message::model();
    // All we need to do is to assign the incoming value to the model we are using...
    if ( isset( $_GET['Message']['Approved'] )){
        $model->approved = $_GET['Message']['Approved'];
    }

    $this->render('index', ['model'=>$model]);
}

// Oh yeah the filter. I just copied your code.
public function approvedFilter(){
    return CHtml::activeRadioButtonList(
        Message::model(), 'approved',  array(0,1),
        array(
           'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'),
           'separator'=>''
        )
    );
}
```

*This code has been tested, but I made some last minute changes, so sorry if it blows up!*
And I still think a simple 'approved:boolean' is much cleaner. ;)